# System.DmlException: Delete failed.SELF_REFERENCE_FROM_TRIGGER

Tags: trigger, exception, apex

Hi All I have written the apex trigger.It working in sandbox but not in Production.While upload the csv file by using apex data loader in production it throws an exception below.

**Exception:**

```
31:04.975 (975279099)|EXCEPTION_THROWN|[29]|System.DmlException: Delete failed. First exception on row 0 with id a3O80000001pJnxxxx; first error: SELF_REFERENCE_FROM_TRIGGER, Object (id = a3N8000000aaaa) is currently in trigger Bidpro_Details_Delete, therefore it cannot recursively update itself: []
12:31:04.975 (975850995)|SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[29]|Database.delete(LIST<SObject>)
12:31:04.975 (975925291)|SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[46]|String.valueOf(Object)
12:31:04.975 (975965515)|SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[46]|String.valueOf(Object)
12:31:04.975 (975987895)|SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[46]|System.debug(ANY)
12:31:04.975 (975997242)|USER_DEBUG|[46]|DEBUG|ERROR : Trigger BidDeleteTrigger_Delete :System.DmlException: Delete failed. First exception on row 0 with id a3O80000001pJnxxxx; first error: SELF_REFERENCE_FROM_TRIGGER, Object (id = a3N8000000aaaa) is currently in trigger Delete, therefore it cannot recursively update itself: []
12:31:04.976 (976004076)|SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[46]|System.debug(ANY)
```

**Apex Trigger:**

```
Trigger BidDeleteTrigger on Bid__c (BEFORE UPDATE)
{   

    TRY
    {
        LIST<Bid_line__c> bidline = NEW LIST<Bid_line__c>(); 
        LIST<Id> bidid = NEW LIST<Id>();
        FOR(Bid__c bidpro : Trigger.NEW)  
        {  
             IF(bidpro.Delete__c == TRUE)
             {  
                bidpro.Delete__c = FALSE;       
                bidid.add(bidpro.Id); 
             }
        }
        IF(bidid.SIZE() != 0)
        {    
            bidline = [SELECT ID FROM Bid_line__c WHERE Bid__c IN: bidid LIMIT 50000];
            IF(bidline.size() != 0)                
                  Database.DeleteResult[] del = Database.DELETE(bidline);
        }
     }
     CATCH(EXCEPTION E){
         SYSTEM.DEBUG('ERROR:'+E);
     }   
}
```

Same code is working in Sandbox.It not throws any exception.Can someone please help me.

Comment: Its strange that it is working in Sandbox but if you look in debug log the trigger is calling recursively. Can you plz chk if there is any rollup summary field or any workflow field update?

Comment: Use `AFTER UPDATE` trigger instead. `DELETE` will turn on the `isDeleted` flag to 'true` which is an update to the object. Then it's self reference. Better to use `AFTER UPDATE` trigger context

Comment: Hi @ highfive Can you tell me where I should use the isDeleted flag to 'true'. Okie can I try AFTER UPDATE it is works right?. Please let me know.

Comment: Are you sure the API versions of the triggers are the same on the sandbox as on the production environment?

Comment: Yes both Sandbox and Production API versions are same for the trigger.

Comment: Bid__c  Object have one field Roll-Up Summary (COUNT Bid_ line__c) are using in Production may be it is an issue.please tell me

Comment: Yes rollup summary is causing an issue because rollup summary field will be updated and then again the same trigger will fire again and will cause the issue. It is better to use "AFTER UPDATE"

Answer (score -1):

Change your trigger to After Update.

Comment: Don't know if you realize it or not, but that answer was given in the comments by @tandonprateek along with his reasons as to why; something you've not provided in yours.

Comment: This definitely needs some more information!